# Jquery radiobutton check and uncheck

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons in a group, one of them being:

```
<input type='radio' id='other' name='Group'></input>
<label for='other'>Other:</label>
```

I would like to make it so that i get an alert when the button is checked.  When the radio button becomes unchecked, after being checked, (by selecting another button) I would like to get a different alert message.

JQuery (this is not working):

```
$('input:radio[id="other"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("checked");
        }
        if ($(this).is(':notchecked')) {
            alert("notchecked");
        }           
    }
);
```

Comment: with this code, what does it show?

Comment: @ianace the checked part is bringing up the alert properly, but when i "uncheck" the button, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Write the change event for the radio group, not for each button. Then look to see which radio button is checked

Here is the jsFiddle ref. http://jsfiddle.net/uAR6e/

Comment: this worked! i should have posted all the buttons, but this is a great start. ill accept your answer in 4 minutes. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. As @JQone suggested you need to apply the function to EVERY button:

```
$('input:radio[name="Group"]').change( function(){
    if ($('#other').is(':checked')) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("notchecked");
    }
});
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zZPcH/

Comment: neither of these work.  the first one produces 2 alerts right after the other on check. the second one never brings up the notchecked alert when the button is blurred

Comment: Ahh, I thought it was a checkbox, not a radio button. See @JQone's answer below. I'll update my code...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this):not(:checked)) {
   alert("notchecked");
 }
```